# Unable to access the initialState of a slice in Redux, so I'm having to resort to manually setting the state properties

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a slice called `modal` which is responsible for showing and hiding a modal, using actions `showModal` and `hideModal`.

Here is what it looks like:

```
    export const modal = createSlice({
  slice: "modal",
  initialState: {
      visible: false,
      selectedExpenseId: null
  },
  reducers:{
    showModal: (state, { payload }) => (
      state = {
        visible: true,
        selectedExpenseId: payload
      }
    ), 
    hideModal: (state, {payload}) => (state = state.initialState) 
    //hideModal: (state, {payload}) => (state = {visible: false, selectedExpenseId: null}) 

  }
});
```

`showModal` works as intended, but when I call `hideModal` nothing happens, as it seems I am unable to access `initialState` in this manner. 
When I resort to the commented out line which manually assigns the values in the intended way, it works.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong, as I would obviously prefer to be accessing `initialState` properly. I am new to React and redux, so I'm sure that I'm probably just missing something obvious here.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Both your reducers are currently wrong.  You're seeing "correct" behavior for `showModal` only by accident.

It looks like you're using Redux Starter Kit.  Since that uses Immer inside, there are two ways you can update the state:

1. "Mutate" the contents *inside* the `state` value
2. Create a new immutably-updated value yourself, and return it.

Neither of your reducers are actually doing that correctly.

Assigning `state = something` inside of a reducer does not mutate the contents of `state`, and it is not *returning* a new value.  Instead, it's just changing what the local variable `state` in this function is pointing to.

In addition, there is no `state.initialState` field.

If `showModal` is working, it's only by accident, possibly because the assignment statement is also implicitly returning the result of the assignment.

What you *should* be doing is something like this:

```js
const initialState = {
    visible: false,
    selectedExpenseId: null
};

export const modal = createSlice({
    slice: "modal",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        showModal(state, {payload}) {
            return {visible: true, selectedExpenseId: payload};
        },
        hideModal(state) {
            return initialState;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that you could also have written the reducers like:

```js
showModal(state, {payload}) {
    state.visible = true;
    state.selectedExpenseId = payload;
}
```

(Source: I'm a Redux maintainer, and I wrote Redux Starter Kit.)

Comment: Thank you, Mark!

Comment: A followup question to your answer @markerikson: Which of the two approaches would you choose in this instance and why?

Comment: Given that you've only got two fields in the state, and the `hide` case involves resetting it, I'd probably go with the "return a new object" approach.  If the state was larger, it would be shorter to update it directly.

Comment: That's no accident (`state = something`), that a feature of javascript (multi left-hand assignment)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it's valid syntax.  However, conceptually from the OP's point of view, it _is_ an accident, because it's a misunderstanding of how Immer works.  If it weren't for the fact that they're using an arrow function with an implicit return, `state = something` in a function body would do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the documentation of Redux is mentioned that you will receive a property in the `state` named `initialState` which will be containing the initial state.

Redux does not populate any property in the `state` object by itself unless you do it in your `reducers` or via `initialState`. 
There are various ways in which you can achieve the desired behaviour out of which you mentioned 1 in the question itself.
If you want to access it via `initialState`, then you can follow the below logic:

```
const initialState = {
  visible: false,
  selectedExpenseId: null
};
export const modal = createSlice({
  slice: "modal",
  initialState: {...initialState},
  reducers:{
    showModal: (state, { payload }) => (
      state = {
        visible: true,
        selectedExpenseId: payload
      }
    ), 
    hideModal: (state, {payload}) => (state = {...initialState}) 
  }
});
```

We have used *spread notation* (triple dot {...}) to avoid the mutation of the original `initialState` object.